# Select check box using Python and Selenuim

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

It would be nice if someone knows how to select the checkbox using Selenium with Python.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

no_class = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='icon-literary-collections']/following-sibling::a[1]")
no_class.click
```

and this is the HTML Part :

```
<div class="a-checkbox" style="">
<label for="checkbox-non--classifiable" style="">
<input id="checkbox-non--classifiable" type="checkbox" name="" value="" nodeid="non--classifiable" style="" class="">
<i class="a-icon a-icon-checkbox"></i>
<span class="a-label a-checkbox-label" style="">Non-Classifiable</span>
</label>
</div>
```

I want to select the checkbox "Non-classifiable"  but i couldn't do that  it tried I tried as id, name, link_text but could not detect what should be used?

Comment: Did you try `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='a-checkbox']/input[1]").click()` or try to set the attribute checked of the input to true.

Answer (score 0):

You can try clicking on it by using its text in the xpath and using explicit wait so that the script waits till the element is present on the page.
You can do it like:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Non-Classifiable']")))
element.click()
```

You need to add the following imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='a-label a-checkbox-label']"))).click()
```

**Javascript click:**

```
checkBox=WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='a-label a-checkbox-label']")))
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", checkBox)
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```